# How do I stop "Failure to download extra data files" error with pepflashplugininstaller?

Tags: 13.04, flash

Am running Chromium on 13.04. For the last few days every morning I get a notification that says "Failure to download extra data files." The dialog box specifically indicates pepflashplugin-installer and has a prompt "run this action now."

[image]

If I run the action, no complaints. At some point, the dialog will return. If I run the the installer from the CLI, my system tells me that I already have the latest version.

I read elsewhere to try this:

```
sudo rm -f /var/lib/update-notifier/package-data-downloads/flashplugin-installer.failed
```

This doesn't stop the notification from reappearing.

I've also tried, but the notification immediately reappears:

```
sudo apt-get --reinstall install flashplugin-installer
```

Comment: Where did you get Chromium from? Normally, Chromium doesn't use pepflash. So you shouldn't see such a notice. Have you done something different? If so, please include the relevant information in the question.

Comment: Not sure on where I installed Chromium from. Is there a reason I shouldn't be using pepflash? I do have this PPA in my sources list: http://ppa.launchpad.net/skunk/pepper-flash/ubuntu

Comment: Chromium normally requires (and uses) the Flash Player provided by flashplugin-installer. Pepper Flash comes bundled with Chrome (not Chromium). So you seem to be doing something that isn't "default": using Chrome's Pepper Flash with Chromium. Since your problem is relatively recent, the one thing I can think of is that Chromium is now at v28; it's possible that the ppa providing Pepper Flash hasn't kept pace. I don't know for sure. I just use Google Chrome.

Comment: http://ppa.launchpad.net/skunk/pepper-flash/ubuntu/dists/raring/Release seems quite current.

Comment: Same problem, but with the regular flashplugin-installer. I'm behind a proxy. Despite the fact I used visudo to keep the HTTP_PROXY enviroment variable the message keeps popping up every day, after every boot.

Comment: @Calmarius, please [ask a question](http://askubuntu.com/questions/ask) of your own giving appropriate details.

Answer (score 2):

I removed the  flashplugin-installer and reinstalled it using these steps:
http://www.webupd8.org/2013/04/install-pepper-flash-player-for.html

This is what I did:

```
sudo apt-get remove  flashplugin-installer
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:skunk/pepper-flash
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install pepflashplugin-installer
```

Then check that chromium uses Pepper Flash Player.

```
sudo vim /etc/chromium-browser/default
```

The last line in `default` needs to read

```
. /usr/lib/pepflashplugin-installer/pepflashplayer.sh
```

If not, add it to the file.

Here's what my `default` file reads:

```
# Default settings for chromium-browser. This file is sourced by /bin/sh from
# /usr/bin/chromium-browser

# Options to pass to chromium-browser
CHROMIUM_FLAGS=""
. /usr/lib/pepflashplugin-installer/pepflashplayer.sh
```

That's it. I didn't get bothered by that error anymore.

Comment: If I don't see the pop-up tomorrow morning, I'll know that this process worked; thanks.

Answer (score 2):

This helped me:

```
sudo rm /var/lib/update-notifier/package-data-downloads/*
sudo rm /var/lib/update-notifier/user.d/data-downloads-failed*
```

Comment: I'm on Ubuntu 12.10.

Answer (score 1):

At times its because of your proxy.

When you have set the environment proxy as :

```
http_proxy=proxy.bla.bla.bla:933
https_proxy=proxy.bla.bla.bla:933
ftp_proxy=proxy.bla.bla.bla:933
```

this is not accepted and the download fails. 
(Am not sure why, probably code standard difference)

hence your proxy has to be in full form :

```
http_proxy=http://proxy.bla.bla.bla:933
https_proxy=http://proxy.bla.bla.bla:933
ftp_proxy=http://proxy.bla.bla.bla:933
```

It solve my problem with this simple tweak at least.

Answer (score 0):

This may help: https://launchpad.net/~skunk/+archive/pepper-flash
I must use it since there is at least one site that firefox will not work with (tv programs on http://www.abc.net.au/iview/).

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Answer (score 0):

Just ran across this problem, with the same dialog box popping up every day or so. A variant on what the OP tried worked for me:

```
sudo apt-get --reinstall install pepflashplugin-installer
```

As mentioned in ipt's answer pepper flash (pepflash) is the version of the flash player packaged with Google Chrome and allows you to view video from certain sites that require a player that supports DRM.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem and it boils down to my proxy settings not being used. The easiest solution I've found is to run (note the `-E`)

```
sudo -E apt-get --reinstall install flashplugin-installer
```

when the pop-up horror starts again. Not very elegant but it works for me.