# Failure to download extra data files: flashplugin-installer

Tags: 14.04, updates, flash

Today after finishing the update i got update information

[image]

I have tried clicking on run action now, but by that nothing happens only terminal opens up and then after minute it automatically closes down.

---

**NOTE**:I have seen [question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/317765/how-do-i-stop-failure-to-download-extra-data-files-error-with-pepflashpluginin) related to this, but not sure to use solution as there was pepflashplugin installer while in my case it is only flashplugin installer

Comment: see this answer.http://askubuntu.com/a/319284/146791

Comment: @G_P I pasted the location of file but it is not working :(

Comment: Is that Coldplay on the wallpaper?

Comment: @mwfearnley Yes :)

Answer (score 24, accepted):

I had the same problem and have fixed it with the following two steps from the command line:

1. Removing flashplugin-installer completely with the following command

   ```
   sudo apt-get remove --purge flashplugin-installer
   ```
2. Re-installing flashplugin-installer again with the command

   ```
   sudo apt-get install flashplugin-installer
   ```

Comment: I tried the purge command but I get this error : `E: Unable to locate package falshplugin-installer`. And if I try the `apt-get install` or even the `apt-get upgrade` commands, the terminal says that flashplugin-installer is the latest version!

Comment: What does `apt-cache policy flashplugin-installer` return?

Comment: I just realised I misspelled the package name. Sorry for wasting your time.

Comment: This seems to fix things for me, but only temporarily. I keep having to run it maybe once every two to three weeks (with little changing in between)....

Answer (score 6):

Another command to force the download to be reattempted:

```
sudo pkexec /usr/lib/update-notifier/package-data-downloader
```

I just got this to work in 16.04. This way you don't have to uninstall/reinstall the package. It's the same thing that would happen if you click the "run this action now" button in the GUI.

Comment: 16.04 here too, if I click the "run this action now" button it fails again. Ridiculous.

Answer (score 2):

Running `sudo pkexec /usr/lib/update-notifier/package-data-downloader` I received the following error (links obfuscated due to ask policy):

```
flashplugin-installer: processing...
flashplugin-installer: downloading _http://archive.canonical.com/pool/partner/a/adobe-flashplugin/adobe-flashplugin_20161213.1.orig.tar.gz
Err:1 _http://archive.canonical.com/pool/partner/a/adobe-flashplugin/adobe-flashplugin_20161213.1.orig.tar.gz
  Could not open file /var/lib/update-notifier/package-data-downloads/partial/adobe-flashplugin_20161213.1.orig.tar.gz - open (2: No such file or directory) [IP: 91.189.92.191 80]
E: Failed to fetch _http://archive.canonical.com/pool/partner/a/adobe-flashplugin/adobe-flashplugin_20161213.1.orig.tar.gz  Could not open file /var/lib/update-notifier/package-data-downloads/partial/adobe-flashplugin_20161213.1.orig.tar.gz - open (2: No such file or directory) [IP: 91.189.92.191 80]

E: Download Failed
```

I manually downloaded the file from the URL specified, created a new 'partial' directory in `/var/lib/update-notifier/package-data-downloads`, moved the download to there and then ran the `sudo pkexec /usr/lib/update-notifier/package-data-downloader` command again. Which I think appeared to work (Ubuntu 16.04)

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem, and instead of fixing it with the GUI, I simply did `sudo apt-get remove flashplugin-installer` and `sudo apt-get install flashplugin-installer` from Terminal. The problem was that my internet connection was unstable, but after doing this a couple times I got the entire file downloaded and installed.

Answer (score 1):

Per RNA's advice in another post:

```
sudo rm /var/lib/update-notifier/user.d/data-downloads-failed
```

fixed on 14.04.

I removed this file in 12.04 LTS, no more error message on bootup, 
videos play just fine!

---

Correction: next day error message came back, tried the purge method
and re-installed flashplugin, error message appeared immediately.