# Failure to download extra data files: flashplugin-installer (not a duplicate question)

Tags: apt, 16.04, firefox, google-chrome, flash

This is not a duplicate of: [askubuntu.../failure-to-download-extra-data-files-flashplugin-installer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/525865/failure-to-download-extra-data-files-flashplugin-installer) nor of [askubuntu .../how-do-i-stop-failure-to-download-extra-data-files-error-with-pepflashpluginin](https://askubuntu.com/questions/317765/how-do-i-stop-failure-to-download-extra-data-files-error-with-pepflashpluginin).

The first link is the closest but the accepted answer does not work.

### The Error Screen

[image: Flashplayer Error Screen]

### The Recommended Solution

```
sudo apt-get remove --purge flashplugin-installer
sudo apt-get install flashplugin-installer
```

### The new errors from apt-get

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  bbswitch-dkms dkms libcuda1-361 nvidia-prime
Use 'sudo apt autoremove' to remove them.
Suggested packages:
  x-ttcidfont-conf ttf-bitstream-vera | ttf-dejavu ttf-xfree86-nonfree xfs
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  flashplugin-installer
0 upgraded, 1 newly installed, 0 to remove and 1 not upgraded.
Need to get 6,782 B of archives.
After this operation, 59.4 kB of additional disk space will be used.
Get:1 http://ca.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/multiverse amd64 flashplugin-installer amd64 11.2.202.635ubuntu0.16.04.1 [6,782 B]
Fetched 6,782 B in 0s (17.6 kB/s)                
Preconfiguring packages ...
Selecting previously unselected package flashplugin-installer.
(Reading database ... 336994 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../flashplugin-installer_11.2.202.635ubuntu0.16.04.1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking flashplugin-installer (11.2.202.635ubuntu0.16.04.1) ...
Processing triggers for update-notifier-common (3.168.1) ...
flashplugin-installer: downloading http://archive.canonical.com/pool/partner/a/adobe-flashplugin/adobe-flashplugin_20160913.1.orig.tar.gz
Err:1 http://archive.canonical.com/pool/partner/a/adobe-flashplugin/adobe-flashplugin_20160913.1.orig.tar.gz
  Could not open file /var/lib/update-notifier/package-data-downloads/partial/adobe-flashplugin_20160913.1.orig.tar.gz - open (2: No such file or directory) [IP: 91.189.92.191 80]
E: Failed to fetch http://archive.canonical.com/pool/partner/a/adobe-flashplugin/adobe-flashplugin_20160913.1.orig.tar.gz Could not open file /var/lib/update-notifier/package-data-downloads/partial/adobe-flashplugin_20160913.1.orig.tar.gz - open (2: No such file or directory) [IP: 91.189.92.191 80]

E: Download Failed
Setting up flashplugin-installer (11.2.202.635ubuntu0.16.04.1) ...
```

This problem seems to have ocurred after I removed `google-chrome-beta` but kept the regular `google-chrome`. Google chrome works fine for watching TV shows with pepper flash plug-in but it would be nice to keep firefox as a backup browser if chrome goes down. I believe firefox needs the separate flashplugin.

Is there a glitch in canonical somewhere?

Should I just `apt-get remove purge` flashplugin-installer and not bother `apt-get install` it again?

PS the `ca.` prefix on `ubuntu.com` website name means **Canada** servers for Canonical and has never been a problem before.

Comment: This [Firefox-add-on](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/video-without-flash/?src=ss) works nice for me, you should try it. Flash shouldn't be installed to use this.

Comment: @mook765 Thanks for the link. That will make a good Plan B should `flashplugin-installer` simply be removed instead of fixing the download problem.

Comment: I experienced that the add-on works better than the aged Flash-plugin

Comment: Possibly a simpler "plan B": Enable Canonical Partner in _Software & Updates_ and install the `adobe-flashplugin` package.

Comment: @GunnarHjalmarsson I had never turned that option off, but turning it on and running `sudo apt install flashplugin-installer` made all the errors go away. Thanks! (Care to post an answer so I can mark it solved?)

Comment: @mook765: Actually there is a fresh beta version of Flash Player available now: http://askubuntu.com/questions/817182/2016-firefox-replacement-for-adobe-flash/823307#823307

Comment: My idea was an alternative package (`adobe-flashplugin`) which includes Flash for both Firefox and Chromium without a need for that extra download procedure. ;) (As regards the answer, please feel free to write it yourself.)

Comment: @GunnarHjalmarsson good point on `adobe-flashplugin` I just tried firefox and flash isn't even installed for my "Plan B" backup browser for chrome. I haven't used Chromium in years so `flashplugin-installer` was probably being downloaded with google-chrome-beta which I deleted last week to save space and time...

Comment: Please note that Google Chrome has flash built-in, while Chromium has not. Both Chromium and Firefox need a plugin, and `adobe-flashplugin` provides it for both those browsers.

Answer (score 11):

Credit to [gunnar-hjalmarsson](https://askubuntu.com/users/159370/gunnar-hjalmarsson) for this answer.

Adobe once began life making fonts for Microsoft Windows. Later it became the premiere program for playing videos over the internet and live TV broadcasts (which I use it for). However now HTML5 is commonly used for playing videos in Google's YouTube and FlashPlayer is becoming marginalized.

Within Google Chrome web browser `PepperFlash` support is built in so a separate flash plugin is no longer required for watching flash content. However on my system (perhaps because I deleted Google Chrome Beta) the error in the original question occurred.

The error message:

```
Err:1 http://archive.canonical.com/pool/partner/a/adobe-flashplugin/adobe-flashplugin_20160913.1.orig.tar.gz
```

showed up because Canonical partners was not enabled. I don't remember turning it off but the solution is to turn it on.

### Enable Canonical Partners

To enable partners in Canonical select `System Settings` then `Software & Updates` and then `Other Partners`. This screen appears:

[image: Canonical Partners]

**Check the box to allow partners**.

As Gunnar points out `flashplugin-installer` isn't needed for firefox so `adobe-flashplugin` is a better option to install. Google chrome has flash player support embedded through a process called `Pepper Flash Player` and doesn't need `flashplugin-installer` either.

The final solution is:

```
sudo apt-get remove flashplugin-installer
sudo apt-get purge flashplugin-installer
sudo apt-get install adobe-flashplugin
```

Thanks again to **Gunnar** for his comments to solve the pesky pop-up message.

Although `flashplugin-installer` is in the title and body, the **partner** errors could apply to many situations and I welcome recommendations to change the title, question or answer.

PS I realize remove and purge can be combined into a single line. I also realize `apt-get` is inferior to a solo `apt` in many respects.

PPS Adobe also gets credit for .PDF files although on Linux platform many free alternatives exist.

PPPS I notice there are other boxes not checked off on the screenshot above and if this answer can be improved by explaining them don't hesitate to comment. I am dpkg challenged as recent down votes have proved.

Comment: Nice wrap-up of the comments! A couple remarks: You could as well just have installed `adobe-flashplugin` directly. If you had, `flashplugin-installer` would have been removed anyway. Also, at this time `adobe-flashplugin` provides Flash Player 11, which is pretty old and not sufficient on some sites, so you may also want to check out [this answer](http://askubuntu.com/questions/817182/2016-firefox-replacement-for-adobe-flash/823307#823307). I'm making Flash Player 23 Beta available in a PPA version of `adobe-flashplugin`. As regards your PPPS, I think it would be another question.

Comment: Thanks for the compliment! I'll leave the removal instructions as is in case others reference the answer for a different `extra data file` which isn't auto-removed.  Besides `remove` and `purge` give me a pleasant feeling :). I look forward to Flash Player 23 some day, but I'll probably get it embedded in a Chrome update without knowing it.

Comment: For Chromium (and probably also for Chrome) you have version 22 already, but for Firefox you have version 11.

Comment: I get in my `update-notifier-common` mails: `flashplugin-installer`: downloading
+http://archive.canonical.com/pool/partner/a/`adobe-flashplugin`/adobe-flashplugin_20180109.1.orig.tar.gz - It seems that both plugins are correlated?